# Set duration of Android´s ScrollTo method

Tags: android, smooth-scrolling

is it possible to manage the duration of android´s ScrollTo method? Somebody knows how can I do this? Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
ObjectAnimator objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(view, "scrollY", 0, 250).setDuration(duration);
objectAnimator.start();
```

Comment: Thanks but it says that Class requires API level 11 and I am using 9, is there other solution? thanks

Comment: I have used nineoldandroids like this: ObjectAnimator objectAnimator= ObjectAnimator.ofInt(miscrol, "scrollY", 0, 480).setDuration(duration);
              objectAnimator.start(); but I get this issue:com.nineoldandroids.util.IntProperty.set(IntProperty.java:43), can you help me? thanks